# Find the number of cells to sum to reach a certain amount

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, iwork-numbers

I have a column of values (they are ordered if that matters): `A:A`. I have two values: a starting value `B1` which is also present somewhere in `A:A`, and a goal value `C1`.

Let's say the we can find the value of `B1` at `A24`, I want to know, how many values I have to sum from `A24` downwards to reach the goal value in `C1`.

eg:

```
 A     |B     |C     
 ------+------+-------
 15    | 36   | 140
 22    |      |
 36    |      |         <--- starting here
 42    |      |
 65    |      |         <--- there we are 36+42+65 >140
 75    |      |              result = 3 (3 rows to sum)
```

Comment: We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What about pre-formatted off-topic comments? What is the point of saying that I tried `COUNTIFS`, `SUMIFS`, `INDEX` or `MATCH`  which obviously lead nowhere since I ask the question here? Please tell me what is too broad in my question?

Comment: The point is to indicate that you have at least tried something and tell us was that that something is. [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask): "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **D1** enter:

```
=IF(A1<$B$1,"",A1)
```

and in **D2** enter:

```
=IF(IF(A2<$B$1,"",A2+SUM($A$1:A1))>$C$1,"",IF(A2<$B$1,"",A2+SUM($A$1:A1)))
```

and copy down.  Finally, in another cell enter:

```
=COUNT(D:D)+1
```

[image]

It is also easy to write a User Defined Function *(UDF)* to get the result without all the extra cells.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to use an extra column for intermediate results.

Comment: Doesn't this solution make sums starting from A1 no matter what? Please check my answer too

Answer (score 0):

In **D1** put `=(A1>=B1)*A1`.

In **D2** enter `=(A2>=B$1)*(A2+D1)` and copy down.

In **E1**: `=SUM((D:D<C1)*(D:D>0))+1`, confirm by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.